# This gives me an error ("#element_{{index}}).datepicker()

Tags: jquery

This returns `"element_{{index}}" not recognized`.  I have checked and read event delegation but I want this field to have `datepicker()` on it on load, i.e. `$document.ready(function(){ //some code putting datepicker on element }`.

My question is how to fix so I do not get error.

Comment: Make sure you're not missing any `"`.  Also what is `{{index}}`?

Comment: quotes are in correct places in original.  sorry I did not put it in example.  {{index}} is the index of the row of data we are pulling into the @Html.TextBox

Comment: I think an example is necessary. What other libraries are you using? Because my first guess would be that the `{{index}}` is not replaced properly. You should edit all relevant information into you question via the edit link below the question text.